# How to prevent images from fetching again when using search filter in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, caching, search

I have a react app that basically shows a feed of memes (only image files) and every meme has some tags that can be used to search that particular meme. I have a SearchBar-component:

```
const SearchBar = ({ memes, setSearchResults }) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => e.preventDefault()

  const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    if (!e.target.value) return setSearchResults(memes)
    const searchArray = e.target.value.trim().replace(/-/g, '').split(' ')
    const resultsArray = searchAlg(memes, searchArray) 
    setSearchResults(resultsArray)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="search" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="search-input"
          type="text"
          id="search"
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
        />
        <button className="search-button">Hae</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

...and Memefeed-component

```
const MemeFeed = ({ memes }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {memes.map((meme) => (
        <Meme key={meme.id} meme={meme} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

...and the Meme-component

```
const Meme = ({ meme }) => {
  return (
    <div className="memePost">
      <LazyLoadImage src={meme.url} alt={meme.url} />
      <a
        href={meme.url}
        download={meme.url}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        Download
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The main component basically just provides the MemeFeed component with the searchResults array so only those memes that match the search tags show on the page.

So if I just scroll trough the memefeed (there are about 100 memes) and I look at the network-tab, it shows that the images(memes) are downloaded only once and if I scroll back up there is no refetching of those images.

However when I use the searchBar/filter, it will refetch those same images even though they have been loaded already. The fetching doesnt actually happen when I type in the filter but only when I backspace from the filter.

I looked at the documentation of useMemo but I don't see how that would help me here.

Answer (score 1):

So after a long while it turns out that when devtools are open on chrome there is a checkbox that disables cache on default. Took that off and now the problem is gone.